# PHP to ASP base64_decode

Tags: php, asp.net, image, base64

I have some working PHP code which creates an image from a string of data, and was wondering how to convert it to ASP:

```
$jpg = base64_decode($_POST['imagedata']);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
echo $jpg;
```

Is it something along the lines of the following code?

```
var image = Request.Params["imagedata"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagedata)) return;
var imageContent = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
using (var os = Response.OutputStream)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < imageContent.Length; i++)
    os.WriteByte(imageContent[i]);
  os.Flush();
  os.Close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about Classic ASP (pre .net era) or ASP.Net ???

Comment: sorry I should have specified - working with ASP.Net